# Viber- re-installed 4 times, doesn't receive messages

Tags: samsung, viber-messenger

I'll be soo grateful if someone can help me here:(
I installed APK Viber on my android and i cant get messages from any of my contacts. ever. They get my message and my status is online but i dont get any messages. I also downloaded desktop version but it doesn;t show messages either. I reinstalled 4 times. Sounds familiar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it doesn't work on your desktop also it may be a problem with your viber settings. Try poking around in the app and check if there's an unmute-esq option.

Comment: did you figure it out ? I have the same problem the last 4 days.